# Run some code when any control on a list loses focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Currently, I have this, on my Form.vb:

```
    Private Sub txtBox1_Leave(sender As Control, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBox1.Leave
        'Some code
    End Sub

...
    Private Sub txtBox10_Leave(sender As Control, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBox10.Leave
        'Some code
    End Sub
```

The thing that bothers me is: All those events are doing the same thing. Is it possible to programatically have a list of the relevant controls and iterate through them, adding such events? This would allow me to reduce the amount of code in my application / coding effort. Something like:

```
For Each c As Control in listOfControls
    'Add event for c here which calls method
Next
```

I really think there is a simple way of doing that but everything I've tried so far (such as AddHandler) did not work. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Put `'some code` in a method and call it from wherever or wire them all to the same event handler.  Your `For Each` is a problem because you probably dont want the code to run many times when any of the controls triggers it

Comment: @Plutonix The `For Each` is intended to just add the events to the controls, programatically, so that instead of typing each event handler for each control, the code itself would automatically add that to everything it requires to.

Comment: just `Handles txtBox10.Leave, txtBox10.Leave, txtBox1.Leave, txtBox107.Leave,txtBox121.Leave, txtBox90.Leave...`

Comment: ...or in your loop: `AddHandler c.Leave, AddressOf Controls_Leave` - where `Controls_Leave` is an event handler like `txtBox1_Leave`.

Comment: @VisualVincent This also means that, to get this functionality, I am forced to actually add an event handler the usual way to at least one control on the form? Thanks

Comment: Partially, but you won't need the `Handles <your control>.Leave` part of the method. Though you could also use a [**lambda expression**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions): **Outside your loop:** `Dim handler As EventHandler = Sub(lsender As Object, le As EventArgs) : 'Do stuff : End Sub` **Inside your loop:** `AddHandler c.Leave, handler` (every colon `:` represents a new line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and quite simple, create a method that will add the requested event to the `Control`, pass an array of controls to that method before the form loads:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' add events to all requested controls
        AddEvent(New Control() {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, Button1})
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddEvent(ByVal myControls() As Control)
        For Each c As Control In myControls
            AddHandler c.Leave, AddressOf Control_Leave
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Control_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MsgBox("Control is not in focus")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, I did exactly that as I gathered from the comments and it worked neatly. I am accepting your answer in order to mark it as the working solution.